# magento2, using REST api media upload

Tags: api, magento-2.1, rest-api

I am Trying to upload image using rest api but it gives

```
string(116) "{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_Catalog::products"}}"
```

My code is

```
$configProductData=array(
   "product"=>array(
               "sku"=>"ABC_123456",
              "name"=> "My Product Title Listing",
              "price"=> 425.99,
                "status"=>1,
               "visibility"=> 4,
               "typeId"=> "simple",
                  "weight"=> 15,
                  "mediaGalleryEntries"=>array(
                    "mediaType"=>"image",
                       "label"=> "abc_123456_image",

                       "position"=> 0,
            "disabled"=> false,
            "file"=> "http://www.url.to/product.png",
               "content"=>array(
                   "base64EncodedData"=>"string",
                     "type"=> "string",
                     "name"=> "string"


)

               )


          ),
"saveOptions"=> true


);
$product_url= "http://demo.store.com/magento2/project-community-edition/index.php/rest/V1/products";
$productData = json_encode(array('product' => $configProductData));
$setHaders = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $configProductData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

I can create products without any issue.But image upload is not working

Comment: enable ACL permission for that user/resource

Comment: yes i already do that,but not any progress